# Comparing my input with values in my database

Tags: python, mysql, database

i recently got into programming and i'm having a hard time understanding how things work SO please help me. I created a database using mySQL and i filled it with some data (10 values called ID numbers),if i want the user to enter a value (his ID number) in my program (I'm using python) and i want my program to take this value and compare it with the values in my database then return "Already exists" if any of the values in my DB is equal to the value the user put, how do i do that ? and should i keep using python ? or is there anything that you would recommend to access/work on my databse ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first follow [this mini-tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) to connect Python with MySQL and be able to run MySQL commands in python.

Then it should be as simple as selecting all of the id's from the table and checking if any match with the user input. To select all of the ID's you'd use something like this (change it to match your database):

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ID")
```

You can see a few more examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_select.asp).

I hope this helps.